# Jquery Smoothscroll Function - How to Control Animation Speed?

Tags: jquery, animation, effects, smooth-scrolling

Anyone can help me? Trying to Add a "Slow" function with my smoothscroll and control speed.

Hope to achievie a real "smoothscrolling".

Here are the codes:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.smoothscroll').live('click',function(e){
    $('html,body').animate({
    'scrollTop': $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top+'px'

    });
    e.preventDefault(); 
});

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the animation time as the 2nd parameter to the `.animate()` function (after the options object) like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.smoothscroll').live('click',function(e){
        $('html,body').animate({
            'scrollTop': $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top+'px'
        }, 10000);
        e.preventDefault(); 
    });
});
```

In this example the animation will take 10,000 ms (10 seconds).

Comment: Note animations will bubble so use `.stop()` when required.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer **nbsp**!

Just to update..

**jQuery .live() has been removed in version 1.9 onwards.**

so here what worked for me :

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.smoothscroll').on('click', 'a',function(e){
        $('html,body').animate({
            'scrollTop': $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top+'px'
        }, 10000);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```